# Using custom forms for editing DataRows

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I have a DataSet which I want to visualize and work with. I use DataGridView components to display its tables, but when it comes to adding new rows/editing existing rows, I don't want to use DataGridView's functionality: I want to show a custom form instead, with TextBoxes, and ComboBoxes, and whatnot, and OK/Cancel buttons.

There is a table with Name (string), Forme (string), Image (byte[]), Attr1 (string), Attr2 (string), IsSpecial (bool) columns. Forme and Attr2 are nullable, the others are not, and Image should contain a picture in it. Also, Attr1 and Attr2 must be looked up from another table (which has ID (long), Name (string) columns).

So I create a new form, drop two textboxes, one picturebox, two combobxes, and a checkbox on it. I already have a problem: how to represent DBNull in a textbox/combobox?

Next, the binding itself. I reckon I have to do something like this:

```
class MainForm
{
    // ...
    private void btAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (EditFrom editForm = new EditForm())
        {
            // I have to create a new row, right?
            var newRow = theTable.newStrongTypedRow();

            if (editForm.ShowData(binding) == DialogResult.OK)
                theTable.addStrongTypedRow(newRow);
        }
    }

    private void btEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (EditFrom editForm = new EditForm())
        {
            if (editForm.ShowData(binding) == DialogResult.OK)
                binding.EndEdit();
            else
                binding.CancelEdit();
        }
    }
}

class EditForm
{
    // ...
    public DialogResult ShowData(SomeBinding binding)
    {
        // tie the controls to the datarow which is being edited right now
        BindAllControls(binding);

        // let the user input the data
        return ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

But what do I use for "SomeBinding"? And what sould be inside BindAllControls()? Or maybe I have this all upside down and it's not how I am supposed to represent/edit data? Maybe someone could suggest a book about this topic?

Answer (score 0):

I would think you would want to use a BindingSource to handle all your bindings.
You can configure the controls to bind to the BindingSource and it should handle all of the translation between the controls and the DataSet.

Bindings can be set like this:

    `this.nameTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.testDataBindingSource, "Name", true));`

You could pass in your BindingSource as "SomeBinding".

Comment: Well, that's neat, but what about lookups? I have to bind the comboboxes with a supplementary table... is it reasonable to pass it in with mainTableBindingSource as well? So then I could construct two new BindingSources for it... but again, maybe what I should pass is DataView of some sort? You see, I am writing a sort-a small app, but I'd like to learn some things as well, so I'd like to do all like "big guys".

Comment: I have a few large WinForms applications that use data binding very heavily and it works great.  I try not to use DataSets if I can and bind to my models (objects) instead.  I would recommend looking into that approach. Check this out [http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=7](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=7).  It is kinda old but still valuable.

Comment: Using object binding you can simply pass a class instance around instead of some abstracted data construct.  I find that it also produces much cleaner and understandable code.

Comment: And your look ups can just be a List property on you model objects.

Comment: Could you suggest any articles/books on such an approach? Apparently, I have "typed DataSets" level, and "model objects" level, and I reckon I shouldn't "read the entire database from the disk into DataSets, then populate model objects from DataSets. On a change in model objects, relay the changes back to DataSets and let them transfer that update to the disk" — having two almost identical copies of database in the app's memory doesn't look very appealing to me.

Comment: Are you familiar with or every used any ORM tools like Entity Framework or nHibernate? ORM frameworks persist your objects for you. Check out the nHibernate quick start [http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#quickstart] (http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#quickstart)